# Dos find command?

Tags: unix, find, ms-dos

Are there any utility find commands that you can download and use in DOS which match the UNIX find command?

Comment: Thou shall google for "[gnu find windows](http://www.google.com/search?q=gnu+find+windows)".

Comment: @Zord - great minds

Answer (score 1):

You can use: `dir ipconfig.* /s/p`

Comment: Let me type that very command into a unix prompt - oops!

Comment: You may not have the proper alias. :P

Comment: When providing answers to questions you should not include anything that relies on an alias, as there is no reason to expect the same alias to exist on the other person's machine.

Answer (score 1):

Cygwin will provide you a fairly featured *nix environment in Windows.

http://www.cygwin.com/

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

```
dir *test* /s/b
dir /s/b | findstr /i "test"
```

If you use findstr, you can use /i for case insensitive, /v lines that do not, /b match at beginning of line, /e match at end of line. So findstr is similar to grep. Also, dir /s/b/ad will only return directories while dir /s/b/a-d will only return files.  dir /? and findstr /? will show the complete help.